# How do I prevent the Save File /As dialog from refreshing?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, google-drive

Every time I try to save something (usually in Chrome/ internet to desktop) this annoying thing happens.

1. When I go to "Quick Access" ; or
2. When I am typing the filename, mid word

Then window refreshes and either

1. Takes me back in the left side scroll window to where in the file tree I was :(
2. Takes focus away from the filename window, and definitely removes cursor position (so if editing the filename, you need to get the cursor back in position too)

This is quite annoying behavior.

**Environment**
Windows 10
Google drive installed, mostly save things there FYI

**Tried**
I uninstalled Windows Media Player, but that only worked temporarily (suggested somewhere on the web)

Comment: This is almost certainly due to a shell extension that has been installed into your windows explorer.  This is not how my save file dialog behaves. It might even be google drive itself (but I doubt it).  Google for a tool that will let you control what extensions are installed.. I suggest searching for `shell extension viewer`..  If you have ZERO luck.. then start looking at what is in your windows startup.

Comment: Thanks @SeñorCMasMas. I have done a Extension Viewer dump, here https://pastebin.com/pz2up39c any clues / ideas on how to work this out? Or just try turning things off in order to see what is causing it?

Comment: My garsh that is a ***LOT*** of stuff loaded in both your startup and your explorer!  Programs (like chrome and brave) shouldn't need stuff running at startup or a shell extension so you might start there.  Next.. think about what you actually USE and how heavy it is.  If you don't need or use the shell aspect of it.. disable the shell part.. it doesn't mean that you lose the program.. I myself would use procmon and process explorer to figure out who was playing nice but those tools are difficult to use.

Comment: That worked @SeñorCMasMas thanks.  Please post it as an answer so I can give you some good clicks :)
FYI the post restarted dump: https://pastebin.com/vm6vnsLP
Hopefully hasn't affected to much else... so far I have had a slight issue right clicking in File Explorer, but didn't last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to a shell extension that has been installed into your windows explorer.

This is not how my save file dialog behaves.

It might even be google drive itself (but I doubt it). 
Google for a tool that will let you control what extensions are installed.. 
I suggest searching for shell extension viewer.. 
If you have ZERO luck.. then start looking at what is in your windows startup.

Programs (like chrome and brave) shouldn't need stuff running at startup or a shell extension so you might start there.

Next.. think about what you actually USE and how heavy it is. If you don't need or use the shell aspect of it.. disable the shell part.. it doesn't mean that you lose the program..

I myself would use ***procmon*** and ***process explorer*** to figure out who was playing nice but those tools are difficult to use.